# Connecting to OpenSearchService fails with the message: Request failed: [security_exception] authentication/authorization failure

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, opensearch, aws-credentials

I am trying to connect to OpenSearchService via Java SDK deployed on EC2 instance. I have tried setting the credentials via aws configure but I am getting the following error message:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.opensearch.client.opensearch._types.OpenSearchException: Request failed: [security_exception] authentication/authorization failure] with root cause
org.opensearch.client.opensearch._types.OpenSearchException: Request failed: [security_exception] authentication/authorization failure
```

Here is the output of my aws configure list:

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************2Y4Y shared-credentials-file    
secret_key     ****************NjjN shared-credentials-file    
    region               ap-south-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

My client is set up as follows:

```
@Bean
public OpenSearchClient getClient() {
        SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
        return new OpenSearchClient(
                new AwsSdk2Transport(
                        httpClient,
                        host,
                        region,
                        AwsSdk2TransportOptions.builder().build()));

    }
```

I am able to connect to the opensearch service from my local machine but for some reason I am not able to connect to it via the EC2 instance.

Fine grain access control is also enabled on my domain and I am using the domain level access policy which looks something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:ap-south-1:************:domain/opensearch-domain/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The temporary solution that I used for this was to not let the credentials be picked up from the aws config, but rather assign it in the config class only:

```
@Bean
    public OpenSearchClient getClient() {
        AwsCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
                StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey));
        SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();
        return new OpenSearchClient(
                new AwsSdk2Transport(
                        httpClient,
                        host,
                        region,
                        AwsSdk2TransportOptions.builder().setCredentials(credentialsProvider).build()));

    }
```